# Does empirical evidence exist that suggests that African Americans and/or Latinos are more likely to be Republican if they are in the middle class?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, democratic-party, minorities

While "poor", "middle class" and "upper class" can be defined differently (the US defines the poverty line 2 different ways by two different agencies) are there any studies that conclude in the US minorities are more likely to vote Republican if they are in the middle class, generally speaking?  And while I know that the vast majority of minorities vote Democratic is this less true for the middle-class of them?  So in my mind comparing the middle to the poor and upper classes is intrinsic to this question.  Finally are there any trend lines where this changes over time?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly going to be "yes, more likely" based on what we know about correlation between socioeconomic position and political views, but the devil is always in the detail (numbers in this case). Does the answer "yes by 0.1% difference\*" actually mean anything in the big picture? (*\* I made up that #*)

Comment: [This WP article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2016/09/28/can-trump-win-black-votes-what-we-know-from-5-decades-of-black-voting-data/) links to actual research on the topic of actual political views (not party affiliation)

Comment: Another problem is what elections you look at. From a related WP article: "But African Americans have voted in significant numbers for Republicans in state and local races. For instance Ohio Gov. John Kasich (R) got the support of 26 percent of black voters when he ran for reelection in 2014.". So Presidential race doesn't always map out to more local races as far as partisan support.

Comment: @user4012 If we get to yes, what's the magnitude of the difference?